# Hola, estoy queriendo eliminar todos los datos de todas las tablas creadas en una sentencia, no se si es posible. Si pueden verificar

Tags: mysql

TRUNCATE TABLE categorías, ciudades clientes, compras, condiciones, departamentos,
detallecompras, detalleventas, empresas, formapagos, marcas, mercaderías, países,
proveedores, sucursales, tipoclientes, tipoimpuestos, trabajadores, unidadmedidas, ventas;

Comment: Bienvenido(a) a Stack Overflow, por favor, lee [cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida, además has el [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) y obtén tu primera medalla.

Answer (score 0):

***Puedes recurrir a 2 opciones a mi parecer.***

**1.** *Proceder a eliminar la base de datos y luego crearla nuevamente y ya queda sin las tablas, de la siguiente manera:*

```
drop database base_de_datos; create database base_de_datos;
```

**2.** *La opcion 2 es eliminar como dices, de la siguiente manera:*

```
drop table una_tabla, otra_tabla, una_mas;
```

Si tienes problemas al eliminar todas las tablas como muestro en la opción 2, puedes desactivar el chequeo y luego de elmininarlas las activas nuevamente.

Para desactivar el chequeo debes hacer lo siguiente:

```
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS = 0;
```

Para activarlo después de eliminar las tablas ejecutas lo siguiente:

```
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS = 1;
```

***Esto lo puedes consultar en la siguiente página:***
https://parzibyte.me/blog/2019/01/13/eliminar-tablas-base-de-datos-mysql/

*Espero te sirva.*